# Does each instance of an application create independent connection to DB. DB creds provided using cloud foundry user provided service instance?

Tags: database, service, credentials, cloud-foundry

When we write a service instance to deliver database credentials to application running on cloud foundry (refer link https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html).

If multiple users are accessing the application simultaneously does each request create independent connections to the database or a single database connection is shared by all the requests?

Comment: This is entirely up to your application, and likely the language, runtime, and frameworks you are using. Cloud Foundry makes the credentials from the user-provided service instance available to your app but doesn't control how connections are handled. Can you share more info about your app?

Comment: One thing to consider as you select a service provider, the service plan that you select through your service provider may limit the maximum number of connections your application can make to a database (or another service).  For example, ClearDB has a free tier plan on PWS which limits you to a max of four simultaneous connections.